# How does one add or update a WAR file/folder to the default embedded Jetty server in a Restlet 2.1 Application?

Tags: jetty, restlet

I would like to develop a Restlet 2.1 Java SE or Java EE Application that uses a (default) Jetty server, as opposed to an external Jetty/Tomcat server.

But I would like to configure the WAR file/folder that Jetty is processing, even allowing for stop(), reconfigure() or reload(), start() to happen at run time.  In the external case, I can use setWar("path to war file/folder") from the Jetty API to achieve my goal, so this is plan B.  Plan A is to figure out how to do this from the Restlet 2.1 API.

I cannot see a way to do it and I'm hoping that I'm just missing an obvious, or even not-so-obvious solution.

Comment: Dont think this can be done as Restlet will be started from the servlet container within a context, so it is too late to change then. You can configure jetty however to start a context from any location and load Restlet at the choosen location. Not sure that helps ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Jetty [WebAppProvider](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/) will provide what you need. If not, have a look at my hot swap code for WAR files in an embedded Jetty on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8599399/1111057).